# MVC3: How to change the generic [Required] validation message text?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

When you decorate a model object's property with the `Required` attribute and don't specify `ErrorMessage`  or `ResourceType/Name` you get the validation message in the interpolated form of "The {0} field is required.", where param 0 is the value of the `DisplayName` attribute of that property.

I want to change that default string to something else but I want to keep the generic nature of it, that is I don't want to specify `ErrorMessage` or `ResourceType/Name` for every property of the model object. Where is the default string stored and how can I change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deriving your own attribute is a fair option and probably has the lowest overhead to get started, but you'll need to go back and change all your existing uses of `[Required]`. You (and any others on your team) will also need to remember to use (and teach newcomers to use) the right one going forward.

An alternative is to replace the `ModelMetadataProviders` and `ModelValidatorProviders` to return strings from a resource file. This avoids the drawbacks above. It also lays the groundwork for replacing messages for other attributes (e.g., `MaxLengthAttribute`) and for supporting additional languages.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var stringProvider = new ResourceStringProvider(Resources.LocalizedStrings.ResourceManager);
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedModelMetadataProvider(stringProvider);
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider(stringProvider));
}
```

Here is the full [source](https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib), [documentation](http://docs.griffinframework.net/mvccontrib/), and a [blog post](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/) describing the usage.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried creating a derived class of RequiredAttribute and overriding the FormatErrorMessage method?  This should work:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(string.Format("This is my error for {0}", name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I should read the `DisplayName` metadata property in the `MyRequiredAttribute` constructor (instead of passing it explicitly), since I already have/need DisplayName defined.

Comment: According to the below link, the 'name' parameter is the name that's to be included in the formatted message.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.formaterrormessage.aspx