# asp.net mvc override validation message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am working with asp.net mvc 5 and want to change validation message text. For example,

```
[Required]
public string name{ get; set; }
```

I give required validation and the error message appears as : 'The name field is required.' but i want change 'something my text' for all required validations.

I can do this as

```
[Required (ErrorMessage="something my text")]
```

but i don't want repeat this for each parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default validation error message in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Refer this : [How to change the generic validation message text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317259/mvc3-how-to-change-the-generic-required-validation-message-text)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple proposition if you are that much willing to use `Required` attribute with custom error message then why not use `HTML 5` instead 
for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, 
new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "name", required="Name is required"})
```

Other way that I've used In MVC5 is something like this

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {8}      characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
```

I hope this helps in any way

Answer (score 0):

I think that this cannot be avoided. We could use reflection (*Despite the fact that this is not the best practice*), however, **attributes are a static part of the assembly**, which will be extremely problematic to add dynamically, in addition, it will worsen the understandability of your code.

However, if you still want to give it a try, I suggest you check out this answer: [How to add an attribute to a property at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663763/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-property-at-runtime?answertab=scoredesc)

I couldn't make it work, but maybe you can.